# android nfc mime types

Tags: java, android, nfc

Im developing a food ordering system using nfc tags. The idea is storing the restaurant location and the table number on the nfc tag, and when user taps, the app will retrieve specific information(food menu) from server of the restaurant according to the nfc tag stored data.

My problem is, i would like to encrypt my data stored inside the nfc tag using a specific mime type, is there anyway to encrypt my data? or should i just use text/plain and md5 the string?

im using galaxy nexus,4.3

thx in advance^^

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to do this, but you need spesial kind of card like MIFARE Plus and you will be able to use AES encription. Unfortunatly you will need to get specification from NXP and it is availible only with NDA.

Best wishes with your app

Answer (score 0):

You can use the encryption provided in your phone to encrypt your data before you put it into your NDEF record (text/plain will work fine). In that case you are independent from specific chip functionality for encryption.

However that implies that the encryption key(s) will reside on the phone and may be attacked there. Whether this of concern in your case, you need to consider yourself.

Btw: MD5 is a hash function, not an encryption. I would rather go for e.g. AES or 3DES.

Comment: To add to it: instead of using the TNF 0x02 "media_type" with text/plain, you may consider to use the TNF 0x05 "Unknown". This does not carry as much overhead, which consumes space on the tag, but does not give you any benefit.